# Tacx Thru Axle for Giant TCR

Tags: axle, trainer, through-axle, giant

I ordered a [Giant TCR Advanced 1 (2018)](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/at/tcr-advanced-1) and it's on its way. I just remembered that I need to get a thru axle that fits my Smart Trainer ([Tacx Flow Smart](https://www.garmin.com/en-US/p/690890). Sadly I can not seem to find the measurements on Giant's website to order the correct one from Tacx's [selection](https://tacx.com/product/e-thru-trainer-axle/).

I read that it is a 142x12mm, but there are several in that list with that measurements and sadly I don't know which of these would fit. Can anyone help me figure it out?

thanks

**EDIT** Looks like the 2018 version (at least mine) has a quick release (I thought it had a thru axle) and I was able to use the quick release "axle" that was provided with the Tacx Flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specs of the thru-axle that you need are [here](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/gb/tcr---defy-disc-brake-thru-axle--front---rear-). The one that you need is T1707, which is 12×142 with a thread of M12×1.

The T1707 and the T1711 both fit a 142×12 mm with a thread of M12×1. The T1707 has an axle length of 162.5 mm, while the T1711 has an axle length of 175 mm. I couldn't find the TCR specs for this online, but since I ride a Giant Propel Disc, which has the same thru-axles as a TCR, I was able to take mine out of my bike to measure it. I found that it measured 162.5 mm (see photo). This means that the T1707 is the correct axle. [image]

Comment: Thank you for putting in the effort. Have a nice day.

Comment: I work at a Giant store that also sells Tacx trainers, so with any luck I'll be able to dazzle a customer with my product knowledge now that I've done the research already.

Comment: Today I got my bike and it has a quick release (I thought it had a thru axle) so I could use the quick release "axle" that was part of the trainer.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware of the thread you have. The thread in the picture looks like medium thread, although the recommended thru-axle has fine thread.

In case you need medium thread (like me), you need the T1710.