# Tacx Thru Axle Adapter Confusion (thread)

Tags: road-bike, through-axle

I have just received my tacx e-thru adapter after waiting ages but it has a fine thread and doesn't seem to fit my bike. I have a Giant Deffy Advanced, do I need to get the 12x1.5? (142x12mm). On Amazon the T1710 seems to be 170, is this the correct one?

Comment: Related backlink https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/58886/tacx-thru-axle-for-giant-tcr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Robert Axle Project has an [axle finder](https://robertaxleproject.com/axle-finder-2/) that suggests that yes, you need 12 x 1.5 (they'll also [sell you one](https://robertaxleproject.com/product/12x135-142-1-5-mm-resistance-trainer/)).